# wxPython - TextCtrl different behaviour between Linux and Windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, wxpython

using python 2.7 and wxpython as GUI API I'm getting two different behaviour on TextCtrl if I'm using Winsows or Linux:

using Windows once I run the .py script the TetCtrl is immediately editable, it appears the blinking pipe so I'm able to write text.

Instead, running the same script in Linux I've to click into the TextCtrl for getting the blinking pipe.

The question is, How can I get the TextCtrl editable at sturtup in Linux?

thnks in advance for the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
'your text control'.SetFocus()
```